# Erro na instalação do SQL 2008 Express (Modo Silencioso)

Tags: sql, cmd, instalador

Os parâmetros de instalação estão da forma a seguir, mas ao tentar fazer dá erro e a instalação é abortada.

```
C:\Setup.exe /QS /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES="SQL" /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS" /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=senha
```

Comment: na pasta de instalação do Sql Server contém um arquivo que mostra a descrição do erro, não estou muito lembrado,rsrs mas já fiz um processo de instalação silencioso à um tempo atrás

Answer (score 1):

Coloque também que você aceita os termos de uso: `/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms`.